# verifying if var is infinity change variable value using for loop nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have some vars that some time have value as "Infinity".
I need to check if the value of the var is "Infinity" if is true assign value as 0 to that var. i want to do a for loop there are many vars that i have to check. the value of account3 have to be 0.

```
 var account1 = 111;
 var account2 = 222;
 var account3 = Infinity;
 var account4 = 444;
```

Comment: If you need to process a lot of variables in a loop, then perhaps these variables should be in an array or properties on an object, both of which would allow you to iterate through them.

Comment: You should show what you've tried already, the result you expect, etc, so it's easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your vars, then check each of them, with the `isFinite()` function.

```js
var account1 = 111;
var account2 = 222;
var account3 = Infinity;
var account4 = 444;

const varArray = [account1, account2, account3, account4]

console.log('source array:', varArray)

const mapArray = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(e => isFinite(e) ? e : 0)
}

console.log('modified array:', mapArray(varArray))
```

More about `isFinite()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite

Comment: your code works perfect thanks. How do i assign the new value of 0 to the old variables?

Comment: That should be taken care of in the code on the line **return arr.map**. There’s a ternary operator, that assigns 0 to every **infinite** value. It should be in the resulting array.

Comment: But if you want to “get back” the original variables, then you could use **destructuring**. I think you shouldn’t do that - try to incorporate the array of values into your code, instead of a large number of variables. **Array**s are for holding a large number of values.